# PHP HTML table as Excel .xls file

Tags: php, html, excel

I have some sripts in PHP that create a table and save it as and `xls` file. And all was working perfect, editing the info inside the sheet. But a few days ago, when I open one of that files, and edit a cell data, and try to save, Microsoft Excel try to save the file as HTML, even if the file extension is `xls`

```
$table = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        Some table rows with table data
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>";
```

I save the `$table` variable with `fopen`,`fwrite`,`fclose` in a file, and then I download the file.

I have also tried to download the file directly, and always when I edit, Excel try to save it as HTML.

I've been looking for a solution, but nothing helped me. Any idea how to fix if?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options how you can export HTML table to xls or xlsx.

First one, echoing the content under right headers. This will generate tons of warnings in excel, but xls will be readable:

```
<?php
$excel_file="output.xls";
$table = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Some </td><td>table</td> <td>rows</td> <td>with</td> <td>table</td> <td>data</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$excel_file."");
echo $table;
?>
```

Second one is a bit more smoother, using existing library like PhpSpreadsheet. You can find pretty neat basic example at their github page: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Basic/01_Simple.php

Third one, with usage of JS snippets from [SheetJS JS-XLSX library](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx). Here you can see one basic example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SheetJS JS-XLSX In-Browser HTML Table Export Demo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<![if gt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/shim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/blob.js@1.0.1/Blob.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/file-saver@1.3.3/FileSaver.js"></script>
<![endif]>
<script>
function doit(type, fn, dl) {
    var elt = document.getElementById('data-table');
    var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, {sheet:"Sheet JS"});
    return dl ?
        XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:type, bookSST:true, type: 'base64'}) :
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || ('SheetJSTableExport.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
}
</script>
<div id="container">
<table id="data-table">
<tr><td>Sample1</td><td>Sample2</td><td>Sample3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sample4</td><td>Sample5</td><td>Sample6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sample7</td><td>Sample8</td><td>Sample9</td></tr>
</table>

</div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p id="xportxlsx" class="xport"><input type="submit" value="Export to XLSX!" onclick="doit('xlsx');"></p>
</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

There are tons of other ways as well, and many more libraries which are supporting this functionality. On the very end, dependable on your needs, you can simply create CSV file instead the xls.